# Unable to post json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, post, xmlhttprequest

```
function myAjax(type, url, data){
  url = type == "GET"? (url+"?"+data): url;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
     }
  };
  xhttp.open(type, url, true);

  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    type=="GET"?xhttp.send():xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

myAjax("POST","http://localhost:8008/testv/",
{csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{{csrf_token}}",sss: 'sssssssss',});
```

I'm using `django 2.0` with `python 3.6`. I know `csrf_token` is required to post data and I am passing it. But still in javascript console I get:

> 403 Forbidden error.

In servers console I get:

> CSRF token missing or incorrect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the token suppose to be placed? in the post body? in the url? in a header?

Comment: @Musa I have figured it out. I was missing a header with csrf_token cookie. Anyway without the header the post request is still accepted only when `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is passed along as url parameter. But it throws a `csrf_token is not  present` error while passing the same as a `json`.